# How to update Angular $watchCollection when changing an Attribute

Tags: angularjs

Hello I have a little bit of a problem when I update an attribute of my array of objects in a parent controller.

the $scope.items contain an array of objects.

```
$scope.items = Ticket.items;

$scope.$watchCollection('items', function () {
   console.log("xxxx");
});
```

Now in another controller child controller. I'm looping thrue the Ticket.items (by the way the Ticket is a service that has a property name items that is an array of objet)

```
Ticket.items.forEach(function (item) {
  item.qty = 55;
});
```

Now the problem is that I'm updating a item property of the Ticket.items and the $watchCollection is not executing. It only executes when i push something to the Ticket.items array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a the parameter `true` to the watch, in order to track deep properties

```
$scope.$watch('items', function () {
   console.log("xxxx");
},true);
```

Comment: Well the $scope.$watchCollection('items', function () {
   console.log("xxxx");
},true);  but the $scope.$$watch('items', function () {
   console.log("xxxx");
},true); works fine.

Comment: do you try watch instead of watchCollection?